# How to increase the frequency of touch events in IPhone4?

Tags: ios, dom-events, touch-event

I'm making a web Application that has a dial which rotates on touch move event. Is there a setting to increase the frequency of touch events  on iphone 4? I'm using native Javascript touch events.